# How to keep phone vibrating after locking screen?

Tags: java, android, service, background, vibration

I want to make my app vibrate even after you press power button to turn off the screen. Like in background. I've tried numerous ways like wakelock, intent service, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?? **Working code examples would be REALLY appreciated!!**

Currently my code looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void switch_click(View v){
        Switch simpleSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.my_switch);
        Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if(simpleSwitch.isChecked()){
            long pattern[] = {0, 100};
            mVibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0);
        }
        if(!simpleSwitch.isChecked()){
            mVibrator.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        //Cancels vibrator when pressed back
        Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        mVibrator.cancel();
        finish();
    }
}
```